# Не получается привести репозиторий в порядок

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reset

У меня репозиторий на битбакете, в нём 4 тестовых коммита с комментариями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я создаю на битбакете ветку под названием reviewFailed1 - собираюсь там хранить старые не пофикшенные версии с коментариями.

Делее, я пишу команду `git reset --soft` `01e511b` тем самым "сбрасываю" последний коммит и файлы, которые были в этом коммите остаются проиндексированными. Я вношу исправления в какие либо файлы и снова делаю коммит. Потом отправляю изменения на битбакет в ветку мастер. Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё бы было хорошо. Но проблема в том что если мне к примеру нужно внести изменения в коммит `test2`, то я делаю тот же `reset soft`, что и в предыдущем случае с ключом коммита, который стоит после того, который мне нужно изменить. Получается, что я сбрасываю все предыдущие коммиты в ветке мастер, а не только коммит `test2`. Как этого избежать? На какие команды обратить внимание? Я думаю правильный вариант должен выглядеть примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опишите, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Если рассматривать чисто практическую сторону, то НИКОГДА не следует изменять коммиты после их ПУБЛИКАЦИИ в репозитории (на битбакете), потому что у всех остальных полетит история и хрен они сделают git pull.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman  я скрин выложил вконце, того что хочу получить

Comment: «Я вношу исправления в какие либо файлы и снова делаю коммит.» — судя по результату, вы сделали изменения в ветки reviewFailed1, а в мастере остался последний нетронутый коммит 1da87b3

Comment: то что вы хотите не возможно. не может быть 2 веток с одинаковым названием.

Comment: И изменение коммита без изменения всех следующих за ним коммитов (потомков) тоже невозможно

Comment: каждый коммит имеет ссылку на своего "отца", если вы поменяете "отца", то ссылки станут недействительными. то есть у вас будут потомки без предка.

Comment: Каждый тест это задание, а комент к нему это, то что я должен исправить. Мне нужно что бы в ветке reviewFailed1 оставались "старые" коммиты, те самые к которым были замечания. А мои исправления к замечаниям были уже в ветке master. Я не понимаю как это сделать, если к примеру test4 я исправил и закоммитил и test3 исправил и закоммитил. Но test2 мне не нужно коммитить, а просто оставить в ветке master. Если я не правильно понял ход, того как это делается. Можете поделиться ссылками или описать вкратце как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: Это вам такое задание кто-то дал? Если да, то этот кто-то дурачок, если нет, то сообщаю, что с гитом работают не так и каждое исправление должно быть новым коммитом :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужный вам инструмент называется "интерактивный rebase", его удобно использовать совместно с командой fixup.

Для начала, вам надо закомитить свои исправления с использованием fixup:

```
git commit --fixup (хеш коммита)
```

Одно исправление может исправлять только 1 коммит.

Далее, вам надо провести rebase:

```
git rebase -i --autosquash (хеш базового коммита)
```

Должно открыться окно редактора, в котором будут перечислены коммиты в нужном порядке, с командами pick перед старыми коммитами и командами fixup перед новыми.

После закрытия редактора, если вы не наплодили конфликтов, git создаст исправленную ветку. *Эта ветка будет идти параллельно старой, ответвляясь в месте первого же исправления. Это единственный способ исправить "закопанный" в истории коммит!*

Если есть конфликты - вам придется их разрешить (читайте инструкцию по rebase).

Источник: [GIT tip : Keep your branch clean with fixup and autosquash](http://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html)